# Django User Registration Form not working, no error

Tags: django, forms

Trying to create a simple user registration form in django. Here is my views.py-

```html
def registerPage(request):
    form=UserCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'newapp/register.html', context)
```

And my html template-

```html
<h3>Register</h3>

<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" name="Create User">
 
</form>
```

In the views I imported UserCreationForm like this and following is the url which is working fine-

```html
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm



url-

path('register/', views.registerPage, name="register"),
```

When I try to create a user the form seems to work fine but the user is never created in the admin. It doesn't show up.I refreshed the page and all. There is no error. I created a user from the admin panel just to make sure and it works.

Earlier same form was giving me a CSRF token failure. Rebooting the computer that error went away. Now no error, but also no user.

Curious with no error in sight, when can be reason for this to happen?

Here is how the CMD looks like after few attempts of user creation, see if that gives you any clue-

[image]

Comment: is your models include image field / file field?

Comment: No it is not based on any of my models. I am using user creation form straight from views and I think it saves the data to the built in User model. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys. i just had to import the User model to forms.py and create a form of my own and it did the trick.

Thank you all.